# Using motion to save single images

Tags: raspbian, webcam

I have a webcam running on my RPi. How can I use `motion` to save single images or movies to a file instead of streaming via http?

Comment: if you are using a Pi- then it is Pi related. I edited you question to ask a proper question as it is a really good one and valid for Pi. Please upvote answers and mark any ones that help you solve your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwDLkMPLTw0

and part 2 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAoA_J5HD0M

is exactly what you're looking for.

You'll be editing the /etc/motion/motion.conf (provided you have one webcam) and in that file you'll want to find this section:

```
"############################################################

 Target Directories and filenames For Images And Films
 For the options snapshot_, jpeg_, mpeg_ and timelapse_filename
 you can use conversion specifiers
 %Y = year, %m = month, %d = date,
 %H = hour, %M = minute, %S = second,
 %v = event, %q = frame number, %t = thread (camera) number,
 %D = changed pixels, %N = noise level,
 %i and %J = width and height of motion area,
 %K and %L = X and Y coordinates of motion center
 %C = value defined by text_event
 Quotation marks round string are allowed.

"############################################################
```

You'll want to change the target_dir option below this section to where you want, for example :

```
>target_dir /home/pi/motionpic
```

Make sure the folder is created before-hand

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider using nginx with rtmp-module. You have to compile it and you can [find a guide I made here.](http://pkula.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/live-video-stream-from-raspberry-pi.html) You will have to skip a few part as that guide is to use the Pi Camera module.

I used these keyframes and it works really well. All you have to do is package your stream as flv and direct it to localhost nginx-rtmp. [It has allot of other features](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module).

in the server part you put this in

```
# record 10 video keyframes (no audio) every 2 minutes
       record keyframes;
       record_path /tmp/vc;
       record_max_frames 10;
       record_interval 2m;
```